# Rails Activeadmin - custom association select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

In my Rails application, I have the following model:

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ideas
end
```

I am creating [ActiveAdmin](http://www.activeadmin.info/) CRUD for my `Idea` model with the custom form that looks something like that looks something like that:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :member
    f.input :description
  end
end
```

The requirement is to have the custom text for a content of the member association, i.e `"#{last_name}, #{first_name}"`.  Is it possible to customize my member select box to achieve it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. I assume you want to use a DropDown list box for `members` to select a user from `User` model.

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :user_id, :label => 'Member', :as => :select, :collection => User.all.map{|u| ["#{u.last_name}, #{u.first_name}", u.id]}
    f.input :description
  end
end
```

Comment: This type of map in collection don't work for me... the activeadmin always shows my u.name instead a u.cod like I set... my collection: User.all.map{|u| [u.cod, u.id]}

Answer (score 0):

For Active Admin You have to pass it as a collection of Hashes. Key in hash will be the text which you want to display and value will be the attribute id.

**For Example:**

```
f.input :user_id, :label => 'Member', :as => :select, :collection => User.all.map{|u| ["#{u.last_name}, #{u.first_name}", u.id]}.to_h

collection: [{name1: 1}, {name2: 2}, {name3: 3}]
```

**Note:** I have added to_h at end of the map which will convert a collection of arrays into a collection of hashes.